# Get profile image from google talk with asmack in android

Tags: android, smack, avatar, asmack

I use asmack to connect with google talk (Android). 
I can get name, email.
I looked [this link](https://gist.github.com/1081548). It uses `"http://profiles.google.com/s2/photos/profile/" + userid + "?sz=" + size;` for google talk image profile.

How do i get userid in `asmack`? 
Or any other ways can i do to get profile image of google talk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `VCard` to load the details of any user using asmack,

> Get Profile Image from google talk?

```
VCard vCard = new VCard();
SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(300000);
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                    new VCardProvider());
vCard.load(connection, user_mail_id);
Log.d("Vcard XML", vCard.toXML()); // complete VCard information
byte[] bs = vCard.getAvatar();   // Avtar in byte array convert it to Bitmap
```

> How do i get userid in asmack?

You have to iterate through the Roster Entries to get user_mail_id,

```
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
Collection<RosterEntry> rosterEntries = roster.getEntries();

for (RosterEntry entry : rosterEntries) {
   String user_mail_id = entry.getUser();
}
```